# edit function on CellContentDoubleClick for a datagridview windows form c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

How to add a edit function in this for the `DataGridView`

```
private void grdBooks_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: As it is, it's difficult to understand your problem. What are you trying to achieve exactly? And why is it not working?

Comment: if you want Edit the cell content in the gridview? // Put the cells in edit mode when user enters them.
dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;

Comment: @VikramBosei tried that it doesnt want to work.

Comment: @NahuelIanni what i want is when i double click the content in the datagridview it should allow me to edit it.

Comment: i tried grdBooks.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
            grdBooks.Columns[1].ReadOnly = false;

Comment: chk this link http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Edit-GridView-Row-on-Double-click-in-ASPNet.aspx